# Using ViewPager in activity and launch app from URL inflating Exception thrown

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, intentfilter

I have a `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` layout in my app and a ViewPager in it for slider. it works fine if, i directly open app.

but when i open app on clicking `URL` it throws inflating Exception on `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` line.

when i remove ViewPager from code it works fine.

Any solution,suggestion please i need it.

or any other way for showing image slider. how i can use both open app from `URL` and show slider

Thanks in advance.

Here is xml code

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.iorzb.malik.proximity.MainActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is Java code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    //image slider
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DepthPageTransformer());
}
```

Here is stacktrace

```
03-05 23:33:08.667 4752-4752/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.iorzb.malik.proximity, PID: 4752
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iorzb.malik.proximity/com.iorzb.malik.proximity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                 at com.iorzb.malik.proximity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
                                                 at com.iorzb.malik.proximity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 6350412 byte allocation with 2543448 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
                                                 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3730)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
                                                 at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
                                                 at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:505)
                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
                                                 at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:241)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationV
```

Comment: Post your code and the stacktrace ...

Comment: @Mark please check this now.

Comment: It's because the linear layout must be inside the drawer layout

Comment: it is inside drawer layout .  activity_main.xml code is inner code of drawer layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are getting RuntimeExceptions about error in layout inflation, you should drill down the trace to see what is the error.

In your case the root cause of your exception is the last trace which is an OutOfMemoryError. It seems that you are allocating large chunks of memory in your ViewPager. Probably showing very large images.

Try using smaller images, or resize them before using.

Comment: i simply added ViewPager with no Image but exception raised. i did try this :)

Comment: One of your menu icons seems to get 6MB when decoded into bitmap. Please check your resources which you're using. Is there any large image there? (in dimensions, not size)