# ViewPager in fragment doesn't work nothing shows up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

Previously i was using ViewPager in Activity class for image slider but there was an issue i posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817763/using-viewpager-in-activity-and-launch-app-from-url-inflating-exception-thrown).
so, i added a fragment and try to add ViewPager in it for image slider but no luck. code executed successfully but ViewPager doesn't show up its contents.

Actually i want to use `image slider` in my home page and also need the functionality to open app from `URL`
Any help! Thanks in advance.

here is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
IAppManager imService;
Boolean mIsBound=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    Fragment fragment= new HomeFragment();
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    }
  }
}
```

here is fragment class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager viewPager;
Timer timer;
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    //image slider
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DepthPageTransformer());


    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }
}
```

here is Adapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.a1,
        R.drawable.a2,
        R.drawable.a3,
        R.drawable.a4,
};
public ImageAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
  return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  //int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
  //imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
  imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the wrong view in your OnCreateView of your Fragment. You're inflating rootView, then you should return that!

Try replacing the:

return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

with

return rootView;

Comment: thank you so much. you saved my day. your answer on link question was not my solution.